# How Do I fix System.MissingMethodException: .ctor When Accessing a Custom Report?

Tags: acumatica

I am getting this error when accessing a custom report in 2019 R2:

[image]

With the same exact customizations and report, I can access this report without error on 2019 R1. Any reasons why I am getting this error on R2?

EDIT: Error requested by HB

[image]

Comment: It looks more like a web service problem then report related. Try 'View Endpoint Service->WSDL' on screen Web Services Endpoint.

Comment: Also check if you have extended endpoints in Web Services Endpoint page.

Comment: I received an error when viewing the WSDL option. Do you want me to add it to the question? I don't believe there are extended endpoints. Is there a speedy way to check?

Comment: I'll post an answer. Please add error message.

Comment: Unfortunately this is the most generic error message returned by web services. I don't think it's version related though. In a new deployment of 2019R2 Open WSDL should work. I would recommend to start with a fresh 2019R2 then publish only the minimum requirements and see if that breaks the web service. The error could be related to endpoint customization or a bad snapshot manipulation.

Comment: I created a new instance, published the customization project related to the report, and got the same error. Any other ideas?

Comment: You need to try without the customization first. The point is to determine if web services access is broken out of box or by the customization. It's the necessary first step of troubleshooting.

Comment: Try unpublishing all customization and deleting all custom endpoints, if error disappear then it's a good test. Otherwise a new deployment is required to determine if web services are broken out of box. I think this is unlikely in a non beta version but can't be ruled out and if that's the case then the environment hosting the website needs to be looked at.

Comment: HB, I installed a fresh version, but I'm not sure what you want me to do to actually test if the Endpoints are properly working. Could you give me some specific instruction? I know you said you don't want me to publish any customization, but the report has custom views and such it relies on to display data. Should I just upload the report and attempt to access it and see if that gives me the same or different error?

Comment: Don't upload anything. Just open 'View Endpoint Service->WSDL' on screen Web Services Endpoint. It's not expected to display an error message out of box. You need to make that work first. When that's done you can re-integrate piece by piece until opening 'View Endpoint Service->WSDL' fails. At that point you should be able to determine which component is breaking the web service functionality.

Comment: Is there a way to tell which endpoint a report is using? I've run the WSDL again on the published version and when running on Default 18.200.001, I get this message: Can't find entity Default/18.200.001.OpportunityProduct Parameter name: qualifiedName Actual value was Default/18.200.001.OpportunityProduct. Does that help narrow down the issue?

Comment: I don't know which endpoint to target. Maybe it's using the first one 17.200.001. It's very important to test it on a fresh deployment. If view wsdl doesn't work in that context then web services are broken in that specific version. More investigation needed as this shouldn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

Reports use soap web service to fetch data. PX.Data.Reports.SoapNavigator points to an  issue with web services access.

Open Web Service Endpoints screen SM207060 and invoke VIEW ENDPOINT SERVICE->WSDL action.

[image]

This should display the WSDL interface of the soap service in XML format. If you have an error here it means the soap web service is not reachable. This could be due to many reasons.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Error>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>Can't find entity Default/17.200.001.KitAssemblyStockComponentAllocation Parameter name: qualifiedName Actual value was Default/17.200.001.KitAssemblyStockComponentAllocation.</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace> at System.Monads.ArgumentCheck.CheckNull[TSource](TSource source, Func`1 exceptionSource) at PX.Api.ContractBased.Edm.Helpers.GetEntityTypeByQualifiedName(IEdmModel model, String qualifiedName) in C:\Bld2\AC-FULL2019R25-JOB1\Sources\NetTools\PX.Api.ContractBased\Edm\Helpers.cs:line 33 at PX.Api.ContractBased.Edm.EntityType.CreateProperty(EntityFieldDescription field) in C:\Bld2\AC-FULL2019R25-JOB1\Sources\NetTools\PX.Api.ContractBased\Edm\EntityType.cs:line 45 at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer) at PX.Api.ContractBased.Edm.EntityType.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<.ctor>b__0() in C:\Bld2\AC-FULL2019R25-JOB1\Sources\NetTools\PX.Api.ContractBased\Edm\EntityType.cs:line 26 at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue() at PX.Api.ContractBased.Edm.EntityType.get_DeclaredProperties() in C:\Bld2\AC-FULL2019R25-JOB1\Sources\NetTools\PX.Api.ContractBased\Edm\EntityType.cs:line 71 at PX.Api.ContractBased.Soap.WsdlBuilderBase.GetEntitySchema(IEdmEntityType entityType) in C:\Bld2\AC-FULL2019R25-JOB1\Sources\NetTools\PX.Api.ContractBased\Soap\WsdlBuilderBase.cs:line 255 at PX.Api.ContractBased.Soap.WsdlBuilderBase.GetServiceDescription(String url) in C:\Bld2\AC-FULL2019R25-JOB1\Sources\NetTools\PX.Api.ContractBased\Soap\WsdlBuilderBase.cs:line 107 at PX.Api.ContractBased.Soap.WsdlBuilderBase.GetWsdl(String url) in C:\Bld2\AC-FULL2019R25-JOB1\Sources\NetTools\PX.Api.ContractBased\Soap\WsdlBuilderBase.cs:line 58 at PX.Api.ContractBased.Soap.WebApiSoapController.Get(EntityEndpoint endpoint, String company) in C:\Bld2\AC-FULL2019R25-JOB1\Sources\NetTools\PX.Api.ContractBased\Soap\WebApiSoapController.cs:line 57 at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] ) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken) --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()</StackTrace>
</Error>
```

First check if you have extended endpoints with missing entity and try open WSDL on each. Errors can happen when you restore snapshot and have the endpoint declaration in snapshot without the customizations that adds the web service entity.

You can view extended entity in Endpoint Name selector. If left side entity tree view is empty there's likely a problem and you need to delete the corrupted entity or publish their required customization.

[image]

Comment: What is the reason behind using the SOAP for reports? Why don't use direct SQL requests?

Comment: Probably because report designer is an external application and the web service are the entry point for those.